# Получение токена при авторизации ВКонтакте (xNet)

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, xnet

Как сделать авторизацию ВКонтакте на С#? Кучу форумов прочитал, видео смотрел — кто-то говорит про [xNet](https://github.com/X-rus/xNet), кто-то ещё про что-либо. Можно поподробней, как всё это реализовать?

Я пытался на xNet делать, только не понял, как всё-таки отправить запрос получения токена.
Прошу дать отрывок кода получения токена.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: можно использовать vk API, там исопльзуется OAuth, очень легко кстати. Если не сможете разобраться, а сильно нужно - http://vk.com/vovanella95 пишите :)

Comment: https://new.vk.com/dev/auth_mobile Вот здесь указано какие запросы отправлять. Сначала отправить сюда https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=1&display=page&redirect_uri=http://example.com/callback&scope=friends&response_type=token&v=5.52 а потом сюда http://REDIRECT_URI#access_token= 533bacf01e11f55b536a565b57531ad114461ae8736d6506a3&expires_in=86400&user_id=8492  для получения AccessToken. Но сначала надо зарегистрировать свое приложение

Comment: Спасибо, но я сделать через браузер, тогда хотел через xNet. :)

Comment: Делайте через API. API — это официальный, поддерживаемый разработчиками путь. А пытаться сэмулировать браузер у вас не выйдет при сколько-нибудь серьёзном противодействии сайта.

Answer (score 1):

Использовал Xnet и для парсинга Newtonsoft.

```
using(var avtoreg = new HttpRequest()) {
  string danni = avtoreg.Get("https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id=2274003&client_secret=hHbZxrka2uZ6jB1inYsH&username=" + login_polzovatelya + "&password=" + pass_polzovatelya).ToString(); //отправляем Get запрос 
  dynamic json = JObject.Parse(danni); //json
  string access_token = json.access_token; //вытаскиваем токен
  int user_id = json.user_id; //вытаскиваем id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы провести клиентскую авторизацию (Implicit flow) десктоп приложения вам понадобится доступ к управлению браузером чтобы показать форму авторизации пользователю. Таков стандарт OAuth для клиентской авторизации Вот пример с использованием WinForms https://gostash.it/ru/stashes/1463-winforms-oauth-dla-desktop-prilozenij